# Import my own shared library with CMakelists

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

I created a shared library in `CMakeLists.txt` by adding:

```
add_library(mylib SHARED ${SourceDir})
install (TARGETS mylib DESTINATION lib)
```

Now I can see the file `libmylib.so` in the correct folder after installing, but I am not sure how can I import this into another separate project's `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned in CMake there are two ways how to use libraries. If you not sure about existing (and placement) library you should use `find` directive. But if you know you should use library directly. So, if your another `CMakeLists.txt` is part of project where used `libmylib.so` you shouldn't use installed version of it.

Comment: thanks. The the CMakeLists is part of another project

Comment: In this case that `CMakeList.txt` should use `find` directive. But according CMake module (like `FindMyLib.cmake`) should be shipped with the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake allows you to not only install the library, it can also install files which can be used by another project to import all the details about the library target. This allows that imported target to be treated almost the same as if it were part of the target it is imported into.

The first step is to add additional install details to your library's project:

```
add_library(mylib SHARED ${SourceDir})
install(TARGETS mylib
        EXPORT myproj-targets
        DESTINATION lib
)
install(EXPORT myproj-targets
        DESTINATION lib/myproj
)
```

Note the added `EXPORT myproj-targets` to your original `install()` call. This tells CMake to include your `mylib` target in the list of targets it will export as part of the export set `myproj-targets`, which the second `install()` then directs CMake to generate as part of the install step.

In your other project where you want to use the library, you just need to `include()` the file that the second of the above `install()` calls will create. Assuming you install to `${installBase}`, the following will import the details exported by the above and make the `mylib` target available for direct use:

```
include("${installBase}/lib/cmake/myproj-targets.cmake)
add_executable(myexe exeSources.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myexe PRIVATE mylib)
```

You can find a reasonable explanation about how all this works from the [CMake documentation for `install()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) and [this wiki article](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets).